# From known coordinates how to determine what kind of area it is on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coordinates, latitude-longitude

For example, I have coordinates (latitude & longitude), I would like to know the location of this coordinates is on a Road, or Park, or Building on Google Maps. Does Google Maps have such API to return this kind of data? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

what you have now is the Geocoder API [1] , with this you can do a reverse geocoding [2] or in other words you make a request with a latitude and a longitude and you get a formated address (or several) as a response, in the response there is a "types" field that gives you information about the type of address, some of the types supported:[3]  .

[1]https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

[2]https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding

[3]https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types

And there is more you can do with it a suggest you read the documentation.

Also there is the Places API that you can put to work along with the Geocoder with even more types supported:[4].

[4] https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types